# When scripting Azure Devops / TFS API - Is there a way to handle "Get Repo does not exist" error response without exiting?

Tags: git, azure, powershell, tfs, azure-devops

Inside of a TFS pipeline, I am using the Get Repo API within a Powershell script to validate whether a GIT repo exists within TFS before the script initiates the creation of a new GIT repo within TFS.

I have validated that the Invoke-Method syntax is good. When the TFS GIT Repo exists, it returns the values without issue.

When a repo does not exist, the API responds with the following error and exits with code '1'.

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF401019: The 
Git repository with name or identifier TFS-GIT-REPO-NAME-GOES-HERE does not 
exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.","ty
peName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server.GitRepositoryNotFoundException, 
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicK
eyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","typeKey":"GitRepositoryNotFoundException","errorCode
":0,"eventId":3000}
At //filepath/scriptName.ps1
+     $results= Invoke-RestMethod @args
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:Htt 
   pWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShe 
   ll.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

Currently, the Invoke-RestMethod line is structured like this:

```
$results= Invoke-RestMethod @args
```

I would like the script to be able to process this case as "does not exist" without crashing.

Can anyone suggest ways for me to ignore this error code? Any constructive suggestions are welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Hi nuprap, did you get a chance to implement the solution that Darrell Agee suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Comment: I ended up pulling from the Get Repo List API and iterating through the list of returned repos to match. I will post the details on Monday.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly sharing. Always better when you fix it yourself; as you understand how it works!:) You could also mark your reply as an answer. Which will also help others in the community.

Comment: Post updated with solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the Get Repo List API to harvest all repos within a project. [Documentation here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

```
... /_apis/git/repositories?api-version=5.1
```

From there, I checked to see if the Get Repo List results matched any of the repo names that i was looking for. If there was a match, I wrote a notification to the screen, and removed the repo name from my query array.

```
        $getRepoListResultsTemp = tfsRepoAPI $BuildPathStage $apiModeTemp $DIRdata

        $repoCheckArray = $newRepoName.split(",")
        $repoCheckCount = $repoCheckArray.count


        if ($repoCheckCount -gt 0) {

            foreach ($tfsRepoName in $getRepoListResultsTemp[0].value.name) {

                foreach ($repoCheckName in $repoCheckArray) {
                    if ($tfsRepoName -eq $repoCheckName) {
                        write-host "The repo exists. The repo name is $tfsRepoName"
                        $repoCheckArray = $repoCheckArray | ? {$_ -ne $tfsRepoName}
                    }
                }
            }
```

Then I iterated through each of the remaining entries in the query array, wrote a notification to the screen, and returned null for each.

```
            if (-! [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($repoCheckArray)) {
                foreach ($repoCheckName in $repoCheckArray) {
                    write-host "Repo does not exist - $repoCheckName"
                }
                return $null,$null
            }
        }
```

For the names that exist in the repo list, they will then kick off the Get Repo API and gather the necessary data. [Documentation here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/get%20repository?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

```
... /_apis/git/repositories/" + $repoName+ "?api-version=5.1
```

Comment: Hi @nuprap, to get the details of the particular repo, we need to send the repo ID in Get Repo API, how was this done in above script? I mean as part of the last para you have mentioned $reponame... is this repo ID?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the context of your answer you are wanting a try-catch block. This means that if an error happens within the try part it will not crash the program but catch the error and let you decide what to do in the catch part of the block.  If you want more information go [here](https://ss64.com/ps/try.html).  There is also one other section to this called a finally block which executes not matter whether you code fails or not.  This section is completely optional though.

```
try { $results= Invoke-RestMethod @args }
catch { "do nothing or record the error out to a log" }


try { $results= Invoke-RestMethod @args }
catch { "do nothing or record the error out to a log" }
finally { "do something else" }
```

Comment: Thanks! I will also wrap the Get Repo List API call in Try/Catch as you suggest.